# Static routing for static IP on a layer 3 switch

Tags: switch

I'm trying to set a Layer 3 Switch (An HP v1910-48G) on my pension (we have around 30 computers). I've got a 6 IP range (4 IPs + 1 Gateway + 1 broadcast).

I've created 3 VLANs:

VLAN 001: It's a VLAN just for port 1, used for accessing the switch's web interface. It'll be an "useless" port most of the time.

VLAN 002: A VLAN for port 2. It'll hold the ethernet cable which gets out of the ISP's "modem". I set the subnet IP manually to one of the 4 IPs we have.

VLAN 003: A VLAN for all the others ports. It has a subnet on 169.254.10.1/24.

I've also created a static routing for 0.0.0.0 (mask 0.0.0.0) with the next hop set as the ISP Gateway's IP.

On a laptop connected to one of VLAN 003's ports, with a manually set IP address on the VLAN 003 subnet. I can ping 169.254.10.1. I can't ping my ISP's gateway. If I try to tracert to, let's say, 8.8.8.8, I get the following:

1 1ms 1ms 1ms 169.254.10.1

2 * * *

3 * * *

4 * * *

And so on.

What should I do to route one of the 4 IPs and be able to have internet access?

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop probably recognizes that 169.254.0.0/16 is IANA-reserved private address space for link-local networking, and as such traffic addressed like this normally doesn't know about a gateway.  I have never seen that scheme used internally on a LAN like this, and I think that is why you cannot network outside of that VLAN.

Try changing VLAN 003 to a scheme like 192.168.x.y/24 or 10.0.0.0 and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Changed my VLAN 003 to 192.168.2.1/24 and still got the same results (can't ping gateway, and still can't get past my switch on tracert). :\ (edit: but nice catch on the IANA-reserved address, that didn't crossed my mind while I was setting the switch).